# Unable to execute Ansible playbook via REST API call

Tags: python, flask, ansible, gunicorn

I am using Gunicorn as my wsgi and Flask as my web framework.  Flask sits behind Gunicorn, which is managed by systemd for starting, stopping, and passing environment variables.

I have a Flask route that receives a list of ports and a hostname as a JSON object.  This data is then passed to a function which builds an Ansible playbook from a Jinja2 template.  The resulting playbook will deploy resources in AWS so everything is ran using ***localhost*** and ***connection=local***

The playbook is then passed to the following code:

```
def ansible_part(**kwargs):

    p = kwargs.pop('playbook', None)
    h = kwargs.pop('hosts', None)
    group = kwargs.pop('group', None)
    p = p.split('.')
    p.insert(1, '_' + group + '.')
    p = ''.join(p)
    playbook_path = p
    inventory_path = h
    try:
        Options = namedtuple('Options', ['connection', 'module_path', 'forks', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'check', 'diff', 'listhosts', 'listtasks', 'listtags', 'syntax'])
        loader = DataLoader()
        options = Options(connection='local', module_path='%s/' % (ROOT_DIR), forks=100, become=None, become_method=None, become_user=None, check=False,
                    diff=False, listhosts=False, listtasks=False, listtags=False, syntax=False)
        passwords = dict(vault_pass='secret')
        inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=[inventory_path])
        variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
        executor = PlaybookExecutor(  
                playbooks=[playbook_path], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader,  
                options=options, passwords=passwords)  
        results = executor.run()  
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

Running this via systemd there seems to be some kind of permissions issue with Ansible trying to write to a **remote_tmp**, even though everything is local.

This is the error from the Ansible logs (changing the remote temp has no affect):

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1557947091.84-58355327375919 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1557947091.84-58355327375919=\"` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1557947091.84-58355327375919 `\" ), exited with result 127", "unreachable": true}
```

If I do something like the following, outside of systemd, it runs fine:

`nohup /opt/proxy_scaler/proxy_scaler_env/bin/gunicorn proxy_scaler:app -b 0.0.0.0:8700 --timeout 30 -k gevent -w 1 -k eventlet &`

I am trying to figure out how to get around the permissions issue, or figure out what user this is effectively running as and scope the permissions for it appropriately.

Comment: You _think that your are_ but you **are not using** the local connection. And I bet it's because your are using `127.0.0.1` as a hostname instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Can you show your inventory ?

Comment: ```[localhost]
127.0.0.1  ansible_connection=local ansible_python_interpreter=/opt/proxy_scaler/proxy_scaler_env/bin/python2.7```

Comment: Weird..... what user is launching your systemd service ? Are you using `become` in your playbook ? If yes, does the systemd service user have sudo access ? Was your successfull manual test made with root or a user with sudo capacity ?

Comment: for systemd I am simpy doing ```systemctl start scaler.service```.  I have become set to ***False***.  My manual test was as root.  Looking at the output from the Ansible logs it seems it is firing off as root, but I could be wrong:  ```2019-05-16 16:20:54,053 p=28104 u=root ```